# PostgreSQL subquery case sequential scan

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-11

I have 2 tables:

1. `requests`: content 60 million records (Used as a log for the website)
2. `requests_hours`: content few hundreds of rows (keep updating it every minute from `requests` tables)

I have the following simple query , but when I execute it, it takes a about 5 minutes to complete, because Postgres do not use the index of the column `request_time_utc` and just does a sequential scan.

```
SELECT COUNT(request_id)
FROM requests
WHERE request_time_utc >= (SELECT MAX(request_hour_utc) FROM requests_hours)
```

[image]

but if I just remove the subquery (which, by itself, is executed in 0.003s) and replace it with a static value like in the following, I get the following query executed in only 0.008s:

```
SELECT COUNT(request_id)
FROM requests
WHERE request_time_utc >= '2019-09-30 17:00:00'
```

[image]

The query should count just a few rows every minute, from 1000 ~ 7000, so certainly an index scan on the column `request_time_utc` should be much better than a sequential scan.

I didn't understand how to force PostgreSQL to do an index scan for the first query.

The above queries are for simplifying the issue; here is the original one:

```
SELECT 
            customer_id,
            DATE_TRUNC('hour', request_time_utc) AS request_hour_utc,
            COUNT(request_id) AS total_requests,
            SUM(data_in_size) AS total_data_in_size,
            SUM(data_out_size) AS total_data_out_size,
            SUM(process_long) AS total_process_long
            FROM requests
            WHERE request_time_utc >= (SELECT MAX(request_hour_utc) FROM requests_hours)
                        AND customer_id IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY request_hour_utc , customer_id
            ORDER BY request_hour_utc DESC;
```

Comment: what if you count on `request_time_utc`? Also consider moving your subquery to CTE.

Comment: actually the query content many other columns and I just simplified it in this way , and the main causer for the issue is the subquery

Comment: After you disclosed your actual query I still would give CTE a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your subquery to CTE, like this (I'm writing this from my phone on the train so you will need to land at the correct query :-) ):

```sql
WITH your_max AS (SELECT MAX(request_hour_utc) as foo FROM requests_hours)
SELECT COUNT(request_id)
FROM requests CROSS JOIN your_max
WHERE request_time_utc >= your_max.foo
```